# The content type "System Page Layout" at "/sites/my-site" is sealed. pnp provisioning engine SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-provision

I'm doing some test copying sites with the **pnp provisioning engine framework** and at **ApplyProvisioningTemplate** content type step I get this error **The content type "System Page Layout" at "..." is sealed.**

The code I'm using is from this repo https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/tree/master/Samples/Provisioning.Framework.Console

Anybody knows what is happening and what can i do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the template.xml that you are using?

Comment: hi @GautamSheth yeah of course here it's:  https://mega.nz/#!6A93yIKQ!0jceGpJ37B6w6ZQfahv4H13EK1G0cMcy1qH_Y7WXxgs

Comment: unfortunately the link is not opening at my end. Can you upload it to Onedrive/Github so that i can test?

Comment: @GautamSheth hi, onedrive link here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq9d0vmIvHFXmDux2x-VLWyPlK9W

Comment: Can you try the xml i have uploaded here and test to see if its working as per your requirement ? 
https://1drv.ms/u/s!AhApeU75Q3r4gZws3_Sm2-FNQ4DozQ

Comment: @GautamSheth, yeah it works, but trying other things i'm getting other errors, how did you solved it? I'm a bit new using this framework, also do you know if must I use two sites with the same template e.g two team sites in order to be able to use this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the OOTB content types like System Page layout, Translation Package etc.

In my opinion, keep only custom content types,fields, lists etc. in the provisioning schema xml. The other content types that are OOTB are automatically added by the site collection/web level features.

I have removed the OOTB content types  like `System Page Layout, Page Layout, Html Page Layout etc` which are present in the `_hidden` group

Below is some of the XML i cleaned up.

```
<pnp:ContentType ID="0x010100E8711F0F931646FA949751442A907B22" Name="Translation Package" Description="Translation Package is a system content type template created by the Translation feature, and it cannot be modified." Group="_Hidden" NewFormUrl="" EditFormUrl="" DisplayFormUrl="">
          <pnp:FieldRefs>
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d" Name="ContentType" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552" Name="SelectFilename" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69" Name="Created" Hidden="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" Name="Title" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f" Name="Modified" Hidden="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9" Name="Modified_x0020_By" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb" Name="Created_x0020_By" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="88fd7ffb-523d-4758-b624-02eaceee1a5d" Name="Translation Package Group ID" />
          </pnp:FieldRefs>
        </pnp:ContentType>
    <pnp:ContentType ID="0x010100FDA260FD09A244B183A666F2AE2475A6" Name="Device Channel Mappings" Description="Device Channel Mappings is a system content type template created by the Mobile and Alternate Device Targeting feature. This content type is used to define device channel mapping files." Group="_Hidden" NewFormUrl="" EditFormUrl="" DisplayFormUrl="">
          <pnp:FieldRefs>
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d" Name="ContentType" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="5f47e085-2150-41dc-b661-442f3027f552" Name="SelectFilename" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="8553196d-ec8d-4564-9861-3dbe931050c8" Name="FileLeafRef" Required="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="8c06beca-0777-48f7-91c7-6da68bc07b69" Name="Created" Hidden="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" Name="Title" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="28cf69c5-fa48-462a-b5cd-27b6f9d2bd5f" Name="Modified" Hidden="true" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="822c78e3-1ea9-4943-b449-57863ad33ca9" Name="Modified_x0020_By" />
            <pnp:FieldRef ID="4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb" Name="Created_x0020_By" />
          </pnp:FieldRefs>
        </pnp:ContentType>
<pnp:ContentType ID="0x01004613D6562E4C41A7B9DADDAC1689E00D" Name="Published Link" Description="Create a New Published Link" Group="_Hidden" NewFormUrl="" EditFormUrl="" DisplayFormUrl="">
      <pnp:FieldRefs>
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d" Name="ContentType" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" Name="Title" Required="true" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="70b38565-a310-4546-84a7-709cfdc140cf" Name="PublishedLinksUrl" Required="true" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="92bba27e-eef6-41aa-b728-6dd9caf2bde2" Name="PublishedLinksDescription" />
      </pnp:FieldRefs>
    </pnp:ContentType>
    <pnp:ContentType ID="0x01004D5A79BAFA4A4576B79C56FF3D0D662D" Name="Reusable Text" Description="" Group="_Hidden" NewFormUrl="" EditFormUrl="" DisplayFormUrl="">
      <pnp:FieldRefs>
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="c042a256-787d-4a6f-8a8a-cf6ab767f12d" Name="ContentType" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" Name="Title" Required="true" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="82642ec8-ef9b-478f-acf9-31f7d45fbc31" Name="LinkTitle" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="9da97a8a-1da5-4a77-98d3-4bc10456e700" Name="Comments" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="3a4b7f98-8d14-4800-8bf5-9ad1dd6a82ee" Name="ContentCategory" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="e977ed93-da24-4fcc-b77d-ac34eea7288f" Name="AutomaticUpdate" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="32e03f99-6949-466a-a4a6-057c21d4b516" Name="ShowInRibbon" />
        <pnp:FieldRef ID="890e9d41-5a0e-4988-87bf-0fb9d80f60df" Name="ReusableText" />
      </pnp:FieldRefs>
    </pnp:ContentType>
```

In the comments, you have mentioned that you are getting some errors, for that you should start small, debug and add only your customizations to the XML file and test.

For example, in the template I am seeing Style library , Pages, Site Assets etc mentioned. These are activated by SharePoint publishing feature or other OOTB SharePoint feature, so you don't need to mention it in XML, you just need to activate the feature and these will be present in the created site.

Also,

> I'm a bit new using this framework, also do you know if must I use
>   two sites with the same template e.g two team sites in order to be
>   able to use this

I dont think you need two team sites to use this.

For reference - [ProvisioningSchema-2016-05-FullSample-02.xml](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/Samples/ProvisioningSchema-2016-05-FullSample-02.xml) check this link for the latest schema